# Display name must be at least 3 chars

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Why make this sudden non-backwards compatible API change?

I've always been "PP" as my display name on the other 5 odd stackexchange websites, so why can't I be "PP" here? It doesn't seem fair or equitable.

Comment: It's not fair or equitable, but it saves them the effort to fix it, so that's the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

3 chars is the new minimum display name, and has been for a while.

Comment: "Hadn't been for much longer".